How to cancel the stars next to the cursor after using copilot in vscode

I couldn't find the option to cancel this in the settings,I have read the relevant documents and have not found any relevant methods. Do you have any relevant experience that can solve my problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

maybe ask authors of vscode

I found a helpful answer here. You can set the following setting:
"editor.lightbulb.enabled": "onCode"

